# What is the "TRIAD" graph and where can I find more information about it?

Tags: architecture, d-wave, adiabatic-model, embedding

I was looking up how to program for a D-Wave machine and I came across this image which says it's the "optimal hardware graph" for a D-Wave machine:

[image]

Unfortunately the image seems to have come from this website: 
http://people.cs.vt.edu/~vchoi/MinorEmbed.pdf (I got a preview somewhere else and they provided a link to this website), and when I click on that link it says "Forbidden You don't have permission to access /~vchoi on this server." The same happens if I remove the PDF from the URL and only look at the faculty member's webpage. The webpage does work if I remove the faculty member's name though, but then it's just the CS department website.

So where can I find the original work where this comes from?
I searched for alternative sources on Google, but it seems that "triad" means very many different things!

Answer (score 2):

Here I found a few resources talking about TRIAD which is a minor embedding technique Vicky Choi introduced :

[Optimizing Adiabatic Quantum Program Compilation using a Graph-Theoretic Framework](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.01996)

[Minor-Embedding in Adiabatic Quantum Computation: I. The Parameter Setting Problem](https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.4884)

[Minor-Embedding in Adiabatic Quantum Computation: II. Minor-universal graph design](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7761/ab691c0261eca2d3361020047522cec046cf.pdf)

The third one contains your image.

Comment: Do you know how to get access to the presentation? Her website was working yesterday

Comment: Unfortunately not. I just found these using Google with the good search queries.